# Can't Edit Config Profile In OpsCenter

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

I installed OpsCenter 6 on an EC2 Ubuntu 14 node.

I used OpsCenter to generate a 5-cluster DSE 5 cluster, one node for each type of workload.  (I excluded hadoop since it is deprecated.)

I've got the cluster working.

Now, when I go back to OpsCenter, and go back into Lifecycle manager, I want to be able to edit the Config Profile so that I can use OpsCenter to maintain the cluster configs.  When I click on Config Profiles, I see two clusters defined.  When I click on my most recently built cluster, I don't see any config template files listed underneath Config Profile for my selected cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpsCenter Lifecycle Manager (aka LCM) developer here...

Your config-profile is almost certainly set to use DSE 5.0.0 as its version. Unfortunately, due to a serious bug (http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html#RNdse__cfs10299), DSE 5.0.0 had to be pulled from distribution. As a result LCM config profiles for DSE 5.0.0 are no longer editable. It would be nice if we had a more obvious error message around this condition, but at this point the config-profile simply shows up as empty.

The workaround is described in https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/211700063-Lifecycle-Manager-Deprecation-of-DataStax-Enterprise-5-0-0. In short, you need to manually upgrade your cluster to DSE 5.0.1 (using apt or yum), then re-create your config profile (either manually if its mostly defaults and re-creating is easy, or using the curl commands if you have heavily customized your CP and can't remember how to manually re-create it).

Removing support for existing versions of DSE is a very rare occurrence, and you shouldn't expect to see a problem like this again soon.

Comment: That explains it.  Thank you!